# Django: Sum up Counts in one query

Tags: python, django

I have a list of elements that i would like to rank according to the count of related manytomany elements. I think aggregating the counts of those source elements is the right way, but i haven't found a solution yet.

```
class Element(models.Model):
     Source1 = models.ManyToManyField(Source1)
     Source2 = models.ManyToManyField(Source2)
     Source3 = models.ManyToManyField(Source3)


Ranked = (Element.objects.all().aggregate(
         Ranked=Sum(F('Source1') + F('Source2') + F('Source3'), output_field=IntegerField)['Ranked']
))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
agg_data = Element.objects.aggregate(total_source1=Count('Source1'), total_source2=Count('Source2'), total_source3=Count('Source3'))
total_count = sum(agg_data.values()) # this is value which you need
```

**Update:**
If you want to get list of Element:

```
res = Element.objects.all().annotate(total_source1=Count('Source1'), total_source2=Count('Source2'), total_source3=Count('Source3'))
.annotate(total_count=F('total_source1') + F('total_source2') + F('total_source3')).order_by('-total_count')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This gives me a sum of Sources but not a list of all the Elements sorted by amout of Sources, right?

Comment: It works, but I shortened it to this:
   `RankedLinks = Link.objects.annotate(ranking=Count('RssEntries')+Count('Tweets')+Count('RedditPosts')).order_by('-ranking').all()`

Thanks!